# Marshaling between unmanaged and managed code

Tags: c#, marshalling, unmanaged

I want to call a c++ function that needs a void pointer as argument. It writes `size` bytes to where to pointer points.
In C# I want to pass a byte array to the function.

However, when the function is called I get a `FatalExecutionEngineError` :
 `The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x725cf46d, on thread 0x2328. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.`

Is the marshalling that I do correct?

c#:

```
[DllImport("Mylib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
            public static extern int MyFunction(In [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] ref byte[] pData, ref int size);
```

c++:

```
MyFunction(void *data, int *size);
```

Comment: Your calling convention `CallingConvention.StdCall` is probably wrong. Try Cdecl instead.

Comment: This is a very dangerous function, it cannot be stopped to write too much data if the array you pass is not big enough.  And yes, that will bomb your program exactly as you describe when the buffer overflow destroys the GC heap.  Don't use dangerous functions like this, fix them.